# Processing a webhook with the microsoftgraph API and Django

Tags: django, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm currently developing a simple web app that connects to an Outlook 365 account through the [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview).
In this app, I'd like to set up a webhook that processes emails upon their reception in the inbox.
However to do so, I need to retrieve a token in order to process the email.

Here is my current Django code :

```
@csrf_exempt
def webhook(request):
    validation_token = str(request)
    validation_token = validation_token.replace(
        "<WSGIRequest: POST '/app/webhook/?validationToken=", "")
    validation_token = validation_token.replace(
        "HTTP/1.1", "").replace("'>", "")

    if len(request.body) == 0:
        request.session['validation_token'] = validation_token
        return HttpResponse(validation_token, content_type="text/plain")
    else:
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        print('received notification(s) !')
        notifications = data['value']
        request.session['notifications'] = notifications
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:categorize'), status=202)
```

The categorize view (in `views.py`), which I'm redirecting to, is supposed to handle the incoming notification (message reception or update). The reason I'm not handling it in the webhook view is because I need to renew a token that should already be stored in the session object. However perhaps maybe because `request` is an incoming POST query, the token isn't stored in the session.

```
def categorize(request):
    access_token, refresh_token, expiration = get_access_token(
        request, request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('app:gettoken')))
    notifications = request.session.get('notifications')
    if notifications is not None:
        account = OutlookAccount(
            access_token=access_token,
            refresh_token=refresh_token,
            token_expiration=expiration
            )
        for resource in notifications:
            resource_data = resource['resourceData']
            client_state = resource['clientState']
            if client_state == 'CLIENT_STATE':
                do_something(resource_data)           
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:mail'))
```

The python function used to retrieve the query (imported from another module) is

```
def get_access_token(request, redirect_uri):
    try:
        current_token = request.session['access_token']
        expiration = request.session['token_expires']
        refresh_token = request.session['refresh_token']
        now = int(time.time())
        if (current_token and now < expiration):
            # Token still valid
            return current_token, refresh_token, expiration
        else:
            # Token expired
            refresh_token = request.session['refresh_token']
            new_tokens = get_token_from_refresh_token(refresh_token, redirect_uri)

            # Update session
            # expires_in is in seconds
            # Get current timestamp (seconds since Unix Epoch) and
            # add expires_in to get expiration time
            # Subtract 5 minutes to allow for clock differences
            expiration = int(time.time()) + new_tokens['expires_in'] - 300

            # Save the token in the session
            request.session['access_token'] = new_tokens['access_token']
            request.session['refresh_token'] = new_tokens['refresh_token']
            request.session['token_expires'] = expiration

            return new_tokens['access_token'], new_tokens['refresh_token'], expiration        
    except KeyError:
        return None, None, None
```

The `gettoken` view gives the endpoint to retrieve the token.

```
def gettoken(request):
    auth_code = request.GET['code']
    redirect_uri = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('app:gettoken'))
    token = get_token_from_code(auth_code, redirect_uri)
    access_token = token['access_token']

    refresh_token = token['refresh_token']
    expires_in = token['expires_in']
    expiration = int(time.time()) + expires_in - 300

    request.session['access_token'] = access_token     
    request.session['refresh_token'] = refresh_token
    request.session['token_expires'] = expiration

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:mail'))
```

I realize that the function `get_access_token` is kinda redundant with the previous view but I'm not sure how to only use the gettoken view to retrieve the authentication token.

To summarize, my main problem is figuring out how to access the `access_token`, `refresh_token` properties which have normally been stored after manual signin. However these aren't accessible in the webhook view (perhaps rightfully so).

What I need is a way to kind of redirect to the `gettoken` view temporarily, store the tokens in the session, and finish processing in the `webhook` view.

I'm sorry if this doesn't make sense, I'm just picking up Django, and I'm not a web developer by trade at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pull the token out of the session because the web hook isn't coming from the user's browser session. It is coming from Microsoft Graph on a remote machine. As such, it looks like another client hitting your backend rather than a message from a given user's session.

If you need to take action based on a webhook notification, you'll need to have the `refresh_token` stored *outside* of the session and a system in place for connecting a given notification to the correct user. With those in place, you can receive a notification, obtain a new token, and make a call into Microsoft Graph on a user's behalf.

Comment: Thanks, I realised I wasn't even using the right application registration method. What I actually needed was an app that doesn't require user interaction to get the token. 
For anyone interested in this, there's documentation here : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service.